# Error when I deploy cloud function Firebase/Stripe

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

this is the first time I try to deploy cloud function in Firebase, usually I use Direbase emulator, but in this case , using Stripe, I am having problems with Cors. When I run the command: `firebase deploy --only functions` , I have no compilation errors, but it tells me that there were errors during the release. Seeing from the Firebase console , I notice that in the logs, it says :

> "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code.

This is my cloud function, I don't understand the error what is:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret_key);
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

export const createCheckoutSessionGreen = functions.region("europe-west6")
    .https.onCall(
        async (data: any, context: any) => {
          const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ["card"],
            mode: "payment",
            success_url: "http://localhost:8100/tabs/types/song",
            cancel_url: "http://localhost:8100/tabs/types/song",
            line_items: [
              {
                price_data: {
                  currency: "eur",
                  product_data: {
                    name: data,
                  },
                  unit_amount: 1.99 * 100,
                },
                quantity: 1,
              },
            ],
          });
          return session.id;
        }
    );
```

Comment: Can you try `exports.createCheckoutSessionGreen = ...` instead of `export const createCheckoutSessionGreen = ...` (CommonJS) since you seem to be using JS? Also you can initialize Admin SDK just by `admin.initializeApp()` (no params so it'll use default credentials)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Typescript with Cloud Function if you want to use the `ES6` syntax. It seems you are using Javascript so try refactoring the code using `exports` instead of `export const`. Also you don't need to pass any parameters to `initializeApp()` since you are deploying to Cloud Functions which will then use [Application Default Credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-without-parameters):

```
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createCheckoutSessionGreen = functions.region("europe-west6").https.onCall(...)
```